# Unity - Google Cardboard camera view without rotating view (iOS)

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-cardboard

I'm looking to use Google Cardboard in Unity 3D, but I don't want the camera to rotate when the user rotates their head.  How would this be done?

Comment: Hi! Have you tried anything so far? StackOverflow isn't a free code-writing service, and expects you to try to [**solve your own problem first**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592). Please update your question to show what you have already tried, showcasing a **specific** problem you are facing in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For further information, please see [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [**tour of the site**](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: Why do you want this?